# How do I connect to the Vivado SDK FPGA serial port?

Tags: sdk, fpga, xilinx, vivado

Why does `/dev/ttyUSB0` disappear once I program the FPGA port using Xilinx Vivado's SDK?  My FPGA program is running as expected, but I'm still trying to connect to the serial port so I can read the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you connect both USB cables to both the `JTAG` and `UART` connections on the FPGA board (and of course connect those cables to your computer).

You'll probably find that `/dev/ttyUSB0` exists right until you program the board.  You'll also probably find that `/dev/ttyUSB1` persists after you program the board.  That's the one you want to connect to via `minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB1`.

Comment: I don't know what to say but I'm having this problem with my Xilinx board since 6 months and I did contact the Xilinx team many times and I was about to give up!! They never mentioned in their emails/forum/manual that both cables should be connected! they clearly ask to connect the JTAG cable only. Really appreciate your help. Many thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :)